# loop through last 5 datalist items GET value & html

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, datalist

I would like to add the last 5 datalist items to the following.  Can someone give some instructions please.

I have this code grabbing the last 5 datalist items.

```
            `var h = document.getElementById("reports").options.length;
            var ind, len, product;
            var len = (h - 5);
            for ( ind = len; ind < h; ind++ ) {
            //this is the value (a url)
            //alert(document.getElementById("reports").options[ind].value); 
            //this is the text between <option>text</option>
            //alert(document.getElementById("reports").options[ind].label);
            }`
```

i would like to add the value from the above 'IND' to (a href) in order on the div id numbers "div111" etc. and the label from above 'ind' (text between the  tags to  in order of the span id numbers 'div11' etc.

```
       ` <div class="notification">
          <img class="" style="color:red" class src="images/bellG.svg">
          <ul class="notification-menu">
            <li>
              <img class="avatar" src="images/ic_note_add_black_36dp.png">
              <p><span id="date1">New Report #01 </span></p>
              <p><a id="div111"><span id="div11"></span></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="avatar" src="images/ic_note_add_black_36dp.png">
              <p><span id="date2">New Report #02 </span></p>
              <p><a id="div112"><span id="div12"></span></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="avatar" src="images/ic_note_add_black_36dp.png">
              <p><span id="date3">New Report #03 </span></p>
              <p><a id="div113"><span id="div13"></span></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="avatar" src="images/ic_note_add_black_36dp.png">
              <p><span id="date4">New Report #04 </span></p>
              <p><a id="div114"><span id="div14"></span></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img class="avatar" src="images/ic_note_add_black_36dp.png">
              <p><span id="date5">New Report #05 </span></p>
              <p><a id="div115"><span id="div15"></span></a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>`
```

Comment: Please fix your post, it's quite hard to understand. I know this sounds silly to ask, but just go through it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking for:

```
var h = document.getElementById("reports").options.length;
var ind, len, product;
var len = (h - 5);
var outputElems = document.querySelector('.notification-menu')
var counter = 0
for ( ind = len; ind < h; ind++ ) {
    outputElems.querySelector(`#div${111 + counter}`).href = document.getElementById("reports").options[ind].value

    outputElems.querySelector(`#div${11 + counter}`).textContent = document.getElementById("reports").options[ind].label

    counter++
}
```

I'm simply adding a counter and targeting the exact elements you want to change inside of a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Thanks much appricated